# Can I post to my Facebook Page from my server without a Facebook App?

Tags: php, facebook

I can log in to my Facebook account and post content on our business page. Is there no way I can do this in an automated way from a server without a "Facebook App"?

Facebook has recently removed our `manage_pages,publish_pages` permissions and replaced them with `user_link,user_gender,user_friends,user_age_range`. I'm now having to wait on them to review our app to reinstate permissions, we've always used and removed the ones we've never used or requested.

To simplify things, can one not simply have a PHP script log in to a user account (mine) and post to a page that way, without using an app?

Comment: No, you can’t. That is not allowed by Facebook’s terms, and they have measures in place against it.

Comment: @Reado, It was with my app some days ago, today `manage_pages,publish_pages` were granted without any doing from me. I can't explain what it means

Comment: those are completely different permissions for completely different usage, manage_pages and publish_pages are not replaced by some user permissions. and no, nothing is possible without an app.